# how to filter repeating data in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have repeating members in category list but i must display only non-repeating members with ng-repeat. How to filter this list to display only non-repeating members  I have example of code.

See my view below

```
<tr ng-repeat="category in cc.categoriesList " 
    ng-click="cc.selectCatForNewTask(category.cid)" 
    ng-class="{selected: cc.getCtgRowClass(category.cid)}"> 
  <td> 
     {{category.categoryName}} 
  </td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: <tr  ng-repeat="category in cc.categoriesList " 
      ng-click="cc.selectCatForNewTask(category.cid)"
      ng-class="{selected: cc.getCtgRowClass(category.cid)}">
 <td>
   {{category.categoryName}}
 </td>
 </tr>

Comment: Conceptually, I'd feel comfortable just using a set to filter out duplicates and then just using `ng-repeat` on this set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="category in cc.categoriesList | unique:category.somefield " ng-click="cc.selectCatForNewTask(category.cid)" ng-class="{selected: cc.getCtgRowClass(category.cid)}">
    <td> {{category.categoryName}} </td> 
</tr>
```

You will need to install some dependencies:

**1.** In your terminal, go to your project and run to install angular-ui-utils unique:

```
bower install angular-ui-utils#bower-unique
```

**2.** Require the unique.js file by adding this to your project below your angular script:

```
<!-- angular script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<!-- unique script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-utils/unique.js"></script>
```

**3.** Add unique as a module to your app:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.unique'])
```

source code available here: [AngularUI unique filter](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js)